# Writing subquery with passing values sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to write subquery that use a value from parent query.

Like this:

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.name,
    (SELECT COUNT(ea.id)
     FROM employee_attendance ea
     WHERE ea.emp_id == e.id) AS attendance
FROM 
    employee e
```

Is there anyway to use this in SQLAlchemy subquery ?

Comment: Some DBMS's will allow what he is doing. I THINK Microsoft SQL Server will allow this.

Comment: is this returning an error? Why won't this work? If it returns an error, what is it? I'm not seeing the connection between your problem and python/sqlalchemy specifically.

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting in this query employee id from parent query passing to subquey. is this possible in sqlalchemy subquery ?